# How to compute item histogram for a column for each particular id group?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Suppose this is the data

```
ID,   EVENT
1      GO
1      GET
1      GO
1      COME
2      FLY
2      GO
2      LEAVE
3      GO
3      COME
....
```

I would like to have a numpy array where each row is the histogram of event counts per ID, like;

Suppose this is the events order [GO, LEAVE, COME, FLY, GET]

```
row1 :  2, 0, 1, 0, 1
row2 :  1, 1, 0, 1, 0
row3 :  1, 0, 1, 0, 0
```

What is the suggested way to do so?

In my very slow implementation, I iterate all the unique ids, find the corresponding rows R, iterate all the events E, count the number of occurrence of that event in R, place the count into row of that id in my numpy array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pandas.groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) followed by [pandas.unstack](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html#pandas.DataFrame.unstack):

```
>>> df
   ID  EVENT
0   1     GO
1   1    GET
2   1     GO
3   1   COME
4   2    FLY
5   2     GO
6   2  LEAVE
7   3     GO
8   3   COME

>>> df.groupby(['ID', 'EVENT']).size().unstack().fillna(0)
EVENT  COME  FLY  GET  GO  LEAVE
ID                              
1         1    0    1   2      0
2         0    1    0   1      1
3         1    0    0   1      0

>>> _.reindex_axis(['GO', 'LEAVE', 'COME', 'FLY', 'GET'], axis=1)
EVENT  GO  LEAVE  COME  FLY  GET
ID                              
1       2      0     1    0    1
2       1      1     0    1    0
3       1      0     1    0    0
```